# Trying to remove subdomain by php explode

Tags: php, validation

Trying to code a validation php for safe database so i have coded till here

problem is this code validates the links with subdomain

like if

```
unsafeurl = http://remove.facebook.com/anything //it works (Shows Valid)
```

but this does not works if

```
unsafeurl = http://facebook.com/anything //not works (Shows invalid because of $da in place of $do ... i have explode (.) here)
```

So, i am stucked at the last line wat to do.. pls help me

```
<?php

      $url=$_POST['unsafeurl']; 

      $safeurl = "facebook";


      $front = explode("/", $url); 
      $host = $front[2]; 

      $domain = explode(".com", $front[2]); 
      $do = $domain[0];

      $domain = explode(".", $url); 
      $da = $domain[1];

      echo $da; 
      echo "<br />"; 

     if($da==$safeurl) {

       echo "valid";

    }
    else
    { 
        echo "invalid";        
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: jh314 Thanks for edit

Comment: How this one is valid `http://remove.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` and why you are comparing it with `facebook`?

Comment: why do you think `parse_url()` exists?

Comment: Khawer Zeshan its a example to vaild if stackoverflow is safe

Comment: while this will work with .com addresses, be careful with things like `www.amazon.co.uk`. `amazon.co.uk` will get trashed down to `co.uk` by your code.

Comment: Khawer Zeshan -  please see my edits...i think knw it will be more clear what is vaild

Comment: Marc B - yea..but it is working in .co.uk domains it is saying valid the only problem is with the subdomain becuz of $da since for co.uk i think it is already checking in $do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change a few things:

```
  $safeurl = "facebook.com";

  # Use parse_url to get host from URL
  $explode = explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));

  # Get last two elements of . explode
  $count = count($explode);
  $count = $count - 2;
  $da = $explode[$count];
  $count++;
  $da .= ".".$explode[$count];
```

This should return `$da` as facebook.com for anything.here.facebook.com

If you want to make it more advanced so it can handle multiple URLs and .co.uk and such:

```
  $safeurl[] = "facebook.com";
  $safeurl[] = "google.co.uk";

  # Use parse_url to get host from URL
  $explode = explode(".", parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));


  $valid = 0;
  foreach($safeurl as $checkurl) { 
    # Get number of elements in safeurl
    $safecount = count(explode(".", $checkurl));

    # Get last $safecount elements of . explode
    $count = count($explode);
    $count = $count - $safecount;
    $da = $explode[$count];
    $count++;
    while ($explode[$count]) {
     $da .= ".".$explode[$count];
     $count++;
    }
    if($da==$checkurl) {
      $valid = 1;
    }
  }
  if ($valid==1) { echo "Valid"; }
```

Someone can verify but I believe that is all correct.  I did it pretty quickly.

Comment: My fault.  I forgot to add the period back in, I have edited my answer (the last line of $da)

Comment: I added some more advanced code to it so you can handle .co.uk and multiple safe urls.  Maybe that will come in handle to you or someone else as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to investigate the PHP `parse_url()` function

Though it is unclear to me what you consider a "safe" URL (does it have to have `.com` TLD? Does it have to be a facebook domain?), this will easily isolate the host portion of the URL for you to inspect.  It will also simply return `false` if the URL is poorly formed.

So you might do something like:

```
$url = $_POST['unsafeurl'];
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
if (false === $host) {
    // bad URL
} else {
    // get domain with TLD removed
    $domain_minus_tld = substr($host, 0, strpos($host, '.', -1));
}
```

If you are specifically trying to verify this is a facebook URL, you might do something like

```
$url_is_facebook = false;
$url = $_POST['unsafeurl'];
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
if (false === $host) {
    // bad URL
} else {
    // see if this is facebook
    $pattern = '/^(www\.)?facebook\.com$/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $host)) {
        $url_is_facebook = true;
    }
}
```